# Reactor flux can't multi thread when on ECS

Tags: multithreading, reactive-programming, amazon-ecs, project-reactor

I was parsing a big size file using flux. Here is the main code
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACe8V.jpg)

I want it to run in multi-threads, which .parallel() -> runOn.boundElastic() can do that.

It works fine on my personal pc, as shown in the pic, there are 5 threads running concurrently [local run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90ILc.jpg)

But when it is deployed on ECS, things goes different. There is just one single thread running. [ecs run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9brs.jpg)

***tests i made***

I don't know if it related to millicores on ecs.

As I made some tests on Ecs, I found that when I requested 500m(millicores) CPU, there is one thread, and when I requested 2000m CPU, there are two threads running.

***question***

But how come it related to CPU cores on ECS?

And what am I supposed to do to make it running on multi-threads, like 10 or more?

**update**

this problem have solved by now.

1. flux.parallel(5)  >> 5 or any number of threads you want to create
2. request more vCPU(Ecs) or millicores(Openshift)

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed related to the number of available CPU cores as that's how the `parallel` operator is implemented in Reactor by default.

The naive solution is to use the overloaded version of the `parallel` operator and pass the parallelization level yourself:

```java
flux
  .parallel(10)
  .runOn(...)
  //...
```

However, note that if the pipeline is doing CPU intensive work, then this will not make your processing any faster as you'll have one CPU core anyway which can only do one thing at a time.

If the pipeline is doing IO intensive work (database calls, HTTP calls, file reads/writes, etc.) then it doesn't make sense to use `ParallelFlux` as that is not intended for this purpose. Instead you can use flatMap operator to make the IO operations concurrent like this:

```java
flux.
  .flatMap(x -> reactiveDatabaseCall(x))
  .flatMap(x -> Mono.fromCallable(() -> blockingIoOperation(x)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()))
```

By default `flatMap` has a concurrency level of 256, meaning it will execute at most 256 items at a given time. If that's too many you can use the overloaded version of `flatMap` where you can pass in the desired concurrency level.

Comment: Thanks for answering. And it is a CPU intencive work in my situation. What im expecting is that even though i have one physical cpu core, i could still have multiple java threads run concurrently. But the problem i met is wierd. On my laptop it created 5 java threads,  On ECS there is just one thread.  the code is the same 
 >>>>  flux.parallel().runOn(schedulers.newBoundElastic(5,1000,"thread-name"))

Comment: If that's really what you want to do then just pass 5 to the parallel method as described in my answer. That should do the trick.

Comment: yes. That did help me, thank you so much!  But im still confused  why the number of thread pool threads created depends on the parallel() method.

Comment: The number of threads created just depends on how you configure the scheduler. Parallel defines the number of threads (rails) used.

Answer (score 1):

Per [the official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html) for ECS Task Definitions, the supported CPU and Memory values are as follows:

| CPU value | Memory value | Operating systems supported for Fargate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 256 (.25 vCPU) | 512 MiB, 1 GB, 2 GB | Linux |
| 512 (.5 vCPU) | 1 GB, 2 GB, 3 GB, 4 GB | Linux |
| 1024 (1 vCPU) | 2 GB, 3 GB, 4 GB, 5 GB, 6 GB, 7 GB, 8 GB | Linux, Windows |
| 2048 (2 vCPU) | Between 4 GB and 16 GB in 1 GB increments | Linux, Windows |
| 4096 (4 vCPU) | Between 8 GB and 30 GB in 1 GB increments | Linux, Windows |

Note the number of **vCPU**. To get multiple CPU cores available you will need to use either `2048` or `4096` as your CPU value in the task definition.

Comment: That hepled me a lot. Thank you!